# Why doesn't this custom logger log info to console and file?

Tags: python

I have a logger function defined in my_logging.py:

```
def my_logger(name):
    print("warn:", name)
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)

    # Create handlers
    c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    f_handler = logging.FileHandler('logs/demo.log')
    c_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    f_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # Create formatters and add it to handlers
    c_format = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    f_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)
    f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)

    # Add handlers to the logger
    logger.addHandler(c_handler)
    logger.addHandler(f_handler)

    return logger
```

Then I use it in test.py:

```
import my_logging

logger = my_logging.my_logger(__name__)

logger.info("This is a test!")
```

It doesn't log at all! The reason I want to put the logger into a function because I want it to be used in multiple modules, using the same logging configuration.

What's the issue here? I tested and seems it has something to do with the handler's setLevel() method. logging.INFO doesn't have an effect.

Comment: it works for me if I add `logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)` inside `my_logger()`

Comment: Yes. my setLevel is inside the my_logger() function.@furas you simply copied the code and it works? That's strange

Comment: you use `setLevel` only for `c_handler` and `f_handler`. You may have to set it also for  `logger`

Comment: Yes, I copied code and it didn't work. But when I set global level - `logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)` - then it starts working.

Comment: @furas, I added logger.setLevel(logging.INFO), and i can print out info, warning and error, but not debug. Why is that? INFO is the lowest level, right?

Comment: if you what DEBUG messages then you have to set level `logging.DEBUG` . Level INFO will not display DEBUG messages. And you may have to set it for `logger`, `c_handler` (if you want debug message on screen) and `f_handler` (if you want debug message in file)

Comment: That's cook, and thanks. It works.

Comment: in doc [setLevel()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) I found that root logger uses WARNING level so it could block INFO levels in handlers

Answer (score 0):

In doc for [setLevel()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) you can see that root logger uses `WARRING` level and probably it blocks `INFO` levels in handlers.

You have to set `INFO` level for root logger

```
logger = logging.getLogger(name)

logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

If you need also `DEBUG` messages then you have to set `DEBUG` level for root logger and for handlers.

```
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

c_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
f_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Using different levels for handlers you can send debug message only on screen or only to file.